# How do I create floating text in Jade (or HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have a Jade file that shows up an error message on pageload if the user attempts to login with incorrect credentials. The problem is the error message moves everything else on the page down whenever it appears, since it's essentially just a paragraph of text.

```
extends layout

block head
    title Login
block content
p
  if (errMessage)
     p= errMessage
br
| Some other text and login boxes here
```

How can I change the message text so that it's essentially floating over everything else and doesn't affect what's behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the container for the error message `position:absolute;`